# Angular 5 Material Paginator resets to negative values when updating pageIndex

Tags: angular, pagination, angular-material2

I'm using an Angular Material data table to display a list of objects that can be added to. When an object is added to the data source, the page index breaks and shows a negative. The only way I've found to fix this is to reset the page index of the material paginator to 0. However, any further changes to the paginator result in a pageIndex of -1 or a broken paginator. Here is an example:

I first set new data in the Angular Material data source like so:

```
private refreshTable() {
    // first we update the length of the paginator with the new length of the datasource data to ensure parity
    this.paginator.length = this.dataSource.data.length;


    // next we get the current page number so we can return to it later.
    let currentPage = this.paginator.pageIndex;

    this.tempSubscription2 = this.rrService.getSearchResults(this.searchEnv.outputPayload(true, true)).subscribe(
        (data: any) => {
            this.extractSBRs(data);
            this.dataSource.data = [];
            // Here is where the dataSource is reset...
            this.dataSource.data = this.sbrs;

            this.paginator.length = this.dataSource.data.length;
            this.paginator.pageIndex = 0;
            this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
            console.log('made it this far');

            if (this.dataSource.paginator.pageIndex < currentPage) {
                console.log('need to return to the current page');
                this.paginator.pageIndex = currentPage;
                this.paginator._pageIndex = currentPage;
                this.dataSource.paginator.pageIndex = currentPage;
                this.dataSource.paginator._pageIndex = currentPage;

            }
        },
        (err: any) => {
        },
        () => {
        }
    );
}
```

When this code is run, updates from the first page are fine because the `this.paginator.pageIndex` is being set to 0. Once an element is added on a page greater than zero, the table shows the first page, the paginator has a pageIndex of -1 and the paginator in the UI looks like this:

[image]

Notice the negative index `-9 - 0`. There seem to be very few examples of updating an Angular Material Data Table and even fewer that have further notes about how updating them effects the Angular Material paginator. How can I get the paginator to go to a pageIndex other than 0 without getting the negative index issue?

I've tried updating just the `this.paginator` which is grabbed via `ViewChild()` per the recommendation [here](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/5812). I've also tried updating the `dataSource.paginator` which you can see in the code above.

Here are my imports:

```
import {
AfterContentInit, AfterViewInit, ApplicationRef, ChangeDetectorRef, 
Component, OnDestroy, OnInit,
    ViewChild
} from '@angular/core';
import { SearchEnvironment } from "../classes/search-environment";
import { SearchFilterDropdown } from "../classes/search-filter-dropdown";
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from "@angular/router";
import {MatTableDataSource, MatPaginator, MatDialog, MatTable, MatSnackBar} from "@angular/material";
import { RemoteRetrievalService } from "../core/services/remote-retrieval.service";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
```

How can I get the desired paginator behavior of returning to the currentPage index without causing a negative index in the `paginator.pageIndex` value or the bad user experience of the negative values in the item(s) range?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is strange how they build some of these components. I am not sure my solution will work, but based upon what I've read in the issue it seems that they can not handle both a `length` change and `pageIndex` change in the same digest cycle.

So I would recommend changing the `length` first, and then later changing the `pageIndex`.

```
 this.paginator.length = this.dataSource.data.length;
 this.paginator.pageIndex = 0;
 this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
 console.log('made it this far');
```

The above sets the values we know will work on the component, and the next part uses `window.setTimeout` to run the next set of changes after the component has had a chance to update itself.

```
 if (this.dataSource.paginator.pageIndex < currentPage) {
     window.setTimeout(()=>{
         this.zone.run(()=>{
            console.log('need to return to the current page');
            this.paginator.pageIndex = currentPage;
            this.paginator._pageIndex = currentPage;
            this.dataSource.paginator.pageIndex = currentPage;
            this.dataSource.paginator._pageIndex = currentPage;
            // EDIT: You must then set the datasource paginator back to the newly edited paginator. 
            this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
         });
     });
 }
```

You will need to inject `NgZone` to run the code inside Angular's zones (which is for error handling). It's just a good practice when using `window.setTimeout`.

Keep in mind that `window` doesn't exist in Angular Universal incase you want to later to do server side rendering, but that's a different issue.

Comment: I'm going to try this right now. Thank you for your answer! I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: The negative index disappears from the paginator with this solution. So that's a win. Unfortunately, the table still returns to the first page which leads the paginator and the table to be out of sync. Any ideas? I'll take a look at the indexes just to make sure it's not something simple.

Comment: It seems like the index is correct but the table still returns to the first page.

Comment: What do you mean by the "table"? is that another component?

Comment: Your solution is correct and I will accept your answer. I submitted an edit because it didn't work completely until I added one more line of code. I couldn't have solved it without your help though. Thank you!

Comment: Cool, I just made a guess. I'm glad it worked. I'll likely need this for myself in the future too.

Comment: How come a non public member `_pageIndex` is being updated ? Is this `MatPaginator` being used in production for applications out there ? I'm having a tough fight to get mine behaving https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53392825/why-is-my-matpaginator-total-number-of-elements-being-overwritten-by-the-number

Comment: Thank you it works for me. Allthought, you don't have to execute a zone.run if you are allready in Angular.
Take a look at the static bool IsInAngular :
https://angular.io/api/core/NgZone#isinangularzone